# the name of event for add or remove the children of inkCanvas using wpf

Tags: wpf, events

I have an Inkcanvas in my project (myPaint)
What is the name of event for add or remove the children (UiElement) from InkCanvas. for example I want handle this event : myInkCanvas.Children.remove(myRectangle) or this example :
myInkCanvas.Children.Add(myRectangle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an event you can listen to that is fired when elements are added to or removed from the Children collection. There is a virtual protected method that is called, which you could leverage, called [OnVisualChildrenChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.onvisualchildrenchanged.aspx).

This isn't directly tied to the Children collection, as elements can add/remove visuals separate from that. But for InkCanvas, it would probably be safe.

So you'd use something like:

```
public class MyInkCanvas : InkCanvas {
    protected override void OnVisualChildrenChanged(DependencyObject visualAdded, DependencyObject visualRemoved) {
        // TODO: Raise event or do something
        base.OnVisualChildrenChanged(visualAdded, visualRemoved);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What exactly do you need this for? Can you use the StrokeCollected event instead?

Comment: No the strokeCollected event used for stroke object and dont used for UiElement for example rectangle or ellipse objects